# VBA Excel R1C1Formulas using cells method

Tags: vba, methods, formula, cells

I've run accross this problem many times and still haven't found the solution or why this won't work. I want to use cells method to enter a formula through a column and so I write this:(just an example)

```
    With ws
        iEndCol = .cells(4650,1).End(Xlup).Column
        For i = 2 To iEndCol
            .Cells(i, 2) = "=VLOOKUP([RC-1],Somesheet!someTable,10,FALSE)"
        Next
    End With
```

when this dosen't work (Method error) I try something like this:

```
    Cells(i,2).Select
    Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)) = False
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP([RC-1],Somesheet!someTable,10,FALSE))"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
```

or instead of .Formula, I try .FormulaR1C1, .Formulalocal etc. and this doesn't work either. Then this is what works:

```
    Range("B2").Select
        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6))
            If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,Somesheet!someTable,10,FALSE)"
            End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
```

What am I not understanding on using Cells to enter formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter a formula using Excel interface (not your code).

Now go to the code editor, press Ctrl+G and type: `? activecell.FormulaR1C1`

The result, `=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Somesheet!sometable,10,FALSE)`, will tell you what you are doing wrong. You are not providing correct RC syntax.

Having that said, you should always ensure your formula syntax matches the property you have picked to set that formula. Use A1 notation for `.Formula`, and RC notation for `FormulaR1C1`. And don't use `.Value` to set a formula.

Answer (score 1):

First, the following worked for me:

```
Set oCell = ActiveCell

Do
    Set oCell = oCell.Offset(0, 1)
    oCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],SomeTable,10,FALSE)"
    Set oCell = oCell.Offset(1, -1)
Loop Until IsEmpty(oCell)
```

Notice that in my syntax, I assumed that `SomeTable` was a defined name with Workbook scope and thus I need no prefix. If `SomeTable` is a defined name scoped to a specific Worksheet, only then do you need to prefix the sheet name (e.g. `Somesheet!SomeTable`).

Second, you should verify in which cell it is trying to put the formula using `Debug.Print oCell.Address`. It may be the case that it is trying to stuff the formula in literally the first column which would cause an error in the formula.